# determining total number of times distinct values 0 or 1 or na in each column in a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, count, counter

I have 15 columns and I want to group by values in each column by either 0 or 1 or na.

## my dataset

```
A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O
0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0
1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0
1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0
NA,1.0,0.0,0.0,NA,0.0,0.0,0.0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA
1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0
1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0
1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0
1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA
1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,NA,0.0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA
1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,1.0
1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0
1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0
1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0
0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,NA,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0
1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0
1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0
0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA
1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0
NA,NA,1.0,NA,NA,0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0
0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,NA,0.0,0.0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA
```

I want output to be like:

```
    A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O
0   5  6  2  3  5  0  1  2  3  4  1  2  0  0  1
1   5  6  2  3  5  0  1  2  3  4  1  2  0  0  1
NA  5  6  2  3  5  0  1  2  3  4  1  2  0  0  1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can loop through the dataset and apply the `table` with `useNA="always"`

```
sapply(df1, table, useNA="always")
```

---

If there are only a particular value in a column, say 1, then convert it to `factor` with `levels` specified as 0 and 1

```
sapply(df1, function(x) table(factor(x, levels = 0:1), useNA = "always"))
#      A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O
#0     4  3  8  7 17 15 14 11 14 12 12 10  8 11  9
#1    19 21 17 17  6  9 10 12  8 11  8 10 12  9 11
#<NA>  2  1  0  1  2  1  1  2  3  2  5  5  5  5  5
```

Comment: I was forgetting factor bit. Thanks